# mongoose .find() showing to much information

Tags: mongoose

Im learning full stack and im following along on a tutorial when I used the .find() it shows alot more information then the tutorial does and it is really confusing me.

i'd like to have just the information that i sent to the db not all the extra information that it provides here

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isPublished: Boolean
})

//Create a model class for Course
const Course = mongoose.model('course', courseSchema);
async function createCourse() {
    const course = new Course({
        name: 'fangular course',
        author: 'yello',
        tags: ['angular', 'frontend'],
        isPublished: true
    })
    const result = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
}

async function getCourses() {
    let courses = await Course.find();
    console.log(courses);
}
```

and i get this i just want the data that i had sent to the db not all this extra

```
removing: undefined,
     inserting: true,
     version: undefined,
     getters: {},
     _id: 5cb60a9fb5f9bc0d742d4ec1,
     populate: undefined,
     populated: undefined,
     wasPopulated: false,
     scope: undefined,
     activePaths:
      StateMachine {
        paths: {},
        states: [Object],
        stateNames: [Array],
        forEach: [Function],
        map: [Function] },
     pathsToScopes: {},
     ownerDocument: undefined,
     fullPath: undefined,
     emitter:
      EventEmitter {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: 0 },
     '$options': true },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc:
   { tags:
      [ 'angular',
        'frontend',
        toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
        _atomics: {},
        _parent: [Circular],
        _cast: [Function: _cast],
        _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
        _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
        '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
        hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
        _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
        push: [Function: push],
        nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
        '$pop': [Function: $pop],
        pop: [Function: pop],
        '$shift': [Function: $shift],
        shift: [Function: shift],
        pull: [Function: pull],
        splice: [Function: splice],
        unshift: [Function: unshift],
        sort: [Function: sort],
        addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
        set: [Function: set],
        toObject: [Function: toObject],
        inspect: [Function: inspect],
        indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
        remove: [Function: pull],
        _path: 'tags',
        isMongooseArray: true,
        validators: [],
        _schema: [SchemaArray] ],
     date: 2019-04-16T17:02:23.832Z,
     _id: 5cb60a9fb5f9bc0d742d4ec1,
     name: 'fangular course',
     author: 'yello',
     isPublished: true,
     __v: 0 } }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: Not sure about your question but I'm using virtual studio IDE and git bash for my terminal is that what you meant